# rich:modalPanel displaying previous row data from rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, richdatatable

I am working with JSF 1.2 where in I am using **rich:dataTable** to display list of user details. User info on each row can be editable thru **commandLink**. Once we click on the command link it will pop up a modal panel with the current value of the user & we can click a edit button on the modal panel to make necessary changes & save the data to database.

The issue I am facing is when ever I click on the edit command link for 2nd row of the datatable, the pop up panel is displaying the user information of 1st row.

Thru command link, I am setting up the currently selected user row value by calling an action method in backing bean & capturing the selected user information as follow

```
<a4j:commandLink value = "Edit" onclick="#{rich:component('UserPopUp')}.show()"  
         action="#{ocrUserBean.captureCurrentUser()}"/>

  public void captureCurrentUser(){
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         currentUser = (User) context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("ocrUser");
}
```

I my modal panel i am displaying the currentUser.getFirstName in an input text.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to send the user id to the bean? If there is a button on each row.

Comment: Makhiel I am able to send the user id thru commandlink also.